# Cant Get Input.GetButton("Jump")

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a FPS game in Unity. I followed a tutorial by Brackeys to create FPS movement in your game. I have all the movement working fine (forward, back, left/right), but for some reason the part of the code that involves jumping is not working. I googled different ways to get the input of the space bar, but none have worked.

Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;
    
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }
        
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }
        
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Hope anyone can help!

:)

Comment: use  `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` instead